# SQL SELECT LIKE containing only specific words

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 LIKE '%word1%'
AND column1 LIKE '%word2%'
AND column1 LIKE '%word3%'
```

I need to modify this query to return records for which column1 contains word1 word2 and word3 and nothing else! no other words, just these words.

Example: searching for `samsung galaxy s3` should return any combination of `samsung s3 galaxy` but NOT `samsung galaxy s3 lte`

Comment: can you elaborate on this part please `"which column1 contains word1 word2 and word3 and nothing else!"`

Comment: Now I get results in which Column1 contains more than these 3 words, like 'word1 word2 word3 word4' and I need results matching the exact specified words in LIKE clause, but in any order.

Comment: At the moment, you're matching on parts of words as well as whole words. Do you want to match `'word1word3word2'` and well as `'word3 word2 word1'`?

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I would like an example of what the preferred output should be if possible, because I still don't understand. Thank :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Assuming* that `column1` contains space separated words, and you only want to match on *whole* words, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (select ' ' + REPLACE(column1,' ','  ') + ' ' as column1 from mytable) t
WHERE
   column1 like '% word1 %' AND
   column1 like '% word2 %' AND
   column1 like '% word3 %' AND
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column1,
      ' word1 ',''),
      ' word2 ',''),
      ' word3 ','') = ''
```

Note that this construction does allow the *same* word to appear multiple times. It's not clear from the question whether that should be allowed. ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4a4b/3))

---

It would be a far better design if these words were stored as separate rows in a separate table that relates back to `mytable`. We could then use more normal SQL to satisfy this query. Your example looks like it's some kind of tagging example. Having a table storing each tag as a separate row (with an ordinal position also recorded, if required) would turn this into a simple relational division problem.

---

A way to count how many times a word appears in a column is the expression:

```
(LEN(column2) - LEN(REPLACE(column2,'word',''))/LEN('word')
```

but this would again revert back to matching subsequences of larger words as well as the word itself, without more work.

Comment: this query returned a result containing only word1 and word2

Comment: @MarioM - I've updated the query because I realised it wasn't doing the "all of these words" portion.

Comment: Now it works better, but it also returns records which does not contain word3

Comment: @MarioM - it shouldn't be able to, since the third `LIKE` would be false.

Comment: This is my query:
   SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
   Model like '%samsung%' AND
   Model like '%galaxy%' AND
   Model like '%s%' AND
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(' ' + REPLACE(Model,' ','  ') + ' ',
      ' samsung ',''),
      ' galaxy ',''),
      ' s ','') = ''

Comment: and it returns 2 rows, 1 contains 'Samsung Galaxy S' and one contains 'Samsung Galaxy'

Comment: I don't need the second row

Comment: I've added a fiddle which shows it working against your original data. The issue is that `s` is a substring of `samsung` so the `LIKE`s register a false positive (as they always did, even in your original question. Give me a second to edit

Comment: @MarioM - please see re-edit - this is the issue I called out in a comment to your original question - you're matching on subsequences within words.

Comment: I have tried your sample on fiddle and it works, but on my database now it does not return any row.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 LIKE 'word1'
AND column1 LIKE 'word2'
AND column1 LIKE 'word3'
```

Comment: With no wildcards and different expressions, no two of those `LIKE`s can ever be true, so the result is always an empty set.

Comment: with this query, I get results which contain only one word, I need the result to return a string containing all 3 words in any order

Comment: Please see the example which I have added to question

Answer (score 0):

in `MySQL` you can use regexp as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1 regexp '^word[1-3]$';
```

in `postgres` you can use '`similar to`' key word

i think oracle also has `regexp`

Comment: i don't know SQLite but i think it will work on MS SQL, you just make a try with sample data