# SQL - Search for exact word match in any order

Tags: sql, search

I have spent the entire day looking for an answer to this and have resolved myself to the fact that it's not possible after 3 different search engine variations. Here's my problem. I need to search a table of printer model numbers. Because printer models aren't standardized, different parts of the model could be in different orders.

**HP OfficeJet Pro 8715**

**HP OfficeJet 8715 Pro**

Both are the same printer obviously but they show up in both ways in the shared DB between us and vendors. The catch is that if I search **HP OfficeJet Pro 8715**, it should return **HP OfficeJet 8715 Pro** as well but it should not return **HP OfficeJet Pro 8715dw** for example.

In summary, the words can be in any order, but the words must match exactly.

I've already parsed the search string into a `#temp` table so that each row has a word and this is how I've been comparing to find results.

```
INSERT INTO #results 
    SELECT Make, Model 
    FROM tDevices 
        WHERE ( Make LIKE '%' + @MAKE + '%' ) AND ( Model LIKE '%' + @MODEL + '%' ) AND ( Model LIKE '%' + @MODEL2 + '%' )
```

Where each model variable is another word in the model. This works great but returns **HP OfficeJet Pro 8715** as well as **HP OfficeJet Pro 8715dw**

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If the `Make` is always at the start just check explicitly against all permutations of the order of words in `Model`?

Comment: Can you make this an answer? This ended up being the best solution for us.

Answer (score 0):

It returns **8715dw**, because the % (*anything* operator) lets it.

Try without the %s:

```
INSERT INTO #results 
    SELECT Make, Model 
    FROM tDevices 
        WHERE ( Make LIKE @MAKE ) AND ( Model LIKE @MODEL ) AND ( Model LIKE  @MODEL2 )
```

Update (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291100/510788):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT Make, CONCAT(' ', REPLACE(Model,' ','  '), ' ') AS Model FROM tDevices) t
WHERE
   Make  LIKE '%hp%' AND (
       Model LIKE '% 8715 %' OR
       Model LIKE '% pro %' AND
       (REPLACE(REPLACE(Model,
       ' 8715 ',''),
       ' pro ','')) = ''
   )
```

Comment: The catch being that without the %s, the search no longer ignores the position of the models right?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't thinking it through, sorry. See my update for a better possible solution.

Comment: Very interesting. It won't solve the whole problem (as it looks like additional words would be included in the search) but I see your point and it's exactly what I need for the first part of the query. Thank you! I'll get it working and hit you up with an answer!